# Apache Pig: Replace null with string

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having a lot of null entries in my data. Due to later processing it would be very helpful if I could set a default value for null to be the string "other". I couldn't find a way to do this (version 0.8.1-cdh3u4)

Also, I have some variables in my GENERATE statements that can potentially return null, and I would need something similar to the SQL DECODE function to get the "other" string instead of null.

Example:

```
tmp = FOREACH dump GENERATE site, REGEX_EXTRACT(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\\.?){1}', 1) AS project, ((ami MATCHES '.*datatype.*') ? REGEX_EXTRACT(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\\.?){5}', 1) : 'other') AS datatype, ami, duid, nbfiles, length, rnbfiles, rlength, name;
```

Here: 'site' and 'datatype' could return an empty string (which is valid) and is interpreted as null, but should be "other" instead.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've been wanting this too.  I don't think it is possible in pig 0.9.2 + piggybank without writing a UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only thing that I could find was the ?: ternary operator. This makes the whole pig script a little bit verbose, but well, it works :-)

```
(((ami MATCHES '.datatype.') ? REGEX_EXTRACT(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\.?){5}', 1) : 'other') IS NULL ? 'other' : ((ami MATCHES '.datatype.') ? REGEX_EXTRACT(name, '^(?:([^.]+)\.?){5}', 1) : 'other')) AS datatype
```

Comment: Hi, IS this worked for integer field too ? You cannot make "IS NULL" command with a integer field right ?